# Azure Devops multi-stage pipeline environment name not set properly

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building a multi-stage pipeline, and I'm using a lot of templates as the deploy  jobs, tasks, and stages for each environment has a lot of shared logic. So on the stage I'm setting a `environmentName` variable, then using that in each of the jobs:

```yaml
  - stage: StageReleaseProd
    displayName: Stage Release (Prod)
    variables:
      environmentName: 'prod'
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployWebApp
        displayName: Deploy Wep App
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImage)
        environment: $(environmentName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - template: config/pipelines/templates/_deploy.task.yml
                  parameters:
                    environmentName: $(environmentName)
```

Often times this works really well. I can see all the environments in the ADO UI and can add approval checks between stages. But I'm also frequently hitting this:

[image]

Sometimes the variable doesn't get interpolated. It feels like this happens 50% of the time, but I also can't deduce a pattern as to why. For now my workaround is to hardcode the environment variable without using parameters, but that severely limits how I can templatize all our pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies with when job name is being populated. In multi stage ADO pipelines if the variable is being used in a job or stage name it is being used at [compile time vs run time.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321)  Try referencing your variable like `${( variables.envronmentName })`

Here are the different ways to reference a variable and the implications of doing so:
[image]

The other thing to call out with variables, as they are a little tricky to keep track of in multi stage pipelines, is that there is the ability to store variables in an ADO variable group. Depending how the solution is structured this may actually simplify things for you.

Another option if you truly want to make this a variable is [define a variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321).  This would be done by creating a seperate yaml file similar to:

```
variables:
  environmentNameDEV: dev
```

Then reference this template in your azure-pipelines-yml file like:

```
variables:
- template: variables.yml
```

And lastly when creating your stage name:

```
- stage: ${{ variables.environmentNameDEV }}
```

Downside is a separate variable name for each environment. Upside is if all repos use the same variable template can ensure consistency across everything with naming standards.

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to work. Instead, I had to move all the stages related to a deployment into a template. Then in the pipeline I would pass a hard coded environment name (ex: "dev") to the template, and within the template I could use the `${( parameters.envronmentName })` syntax. But in the top-level pipeline, no matter how I try to interpolate the variable, it either doesn't work at all, or works 50% of the time which feels like a bug.

Comment: @AndrewCraswell check the update answer I gave as another option that is slightly better then hard coding but still has it's drawbacks.