# How to set a variable from another yaml file in azure-pipeline.yml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an environment.yml shown as follow, I would like to read out the content of the **name** variable (core-force) and set it as a value of the **global variable** in my azure-pipeline.yamal file how can I do it?

```
name: core-force
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - click
  - Sphinx
  - sphinx_rtd_theme
  - numpy
  - pylint
  - azure-cosmos
  - python=3
  - flask
  - pytest
  - shapely
```

in my azure-pipeline.yml file I would like to have something like

```
variables:
  tag: get the value of the name from the environment.yml aka 'core-force'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse):

File: vars.yml

```yaml
variables:
  favoriteVeggie: 'brussels sprouts'
```

File: azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
variables:
- template: vars.yml  # Template reference

steps:
- script: echo My favorite vegetable is ${{ variables.favoriteVeggie }}.
```

Please note, that variables are simple string and if you want to use list you may need do some workaraund in powershell in place where you want to use value from that list.

If you don't want to use template functionality as it is shown above you need to do these:

- create a separate job/stage

  - define step there to read `environment.yml` file and set variables using REST API or Azure CLI
- create another job/stage and move you current build defitnion into there

I found this [topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html) on developer community where you can read:

> Yaml variables have always been string: string mappings. The doc appears to be currently correct, though we may have had a bug when last you visited.
>
> We are preparing to release a feature in the near future to allow you to pass more complex structures. Stay tuned!

But I don't have more info bout this.

Comment: Is it possible to leverage a template also to fill other parts of the pipeline as the matrix strategy? E.g. to create a job per file dynamically, and using a bash script to generate a yaml to use there https://stackoverflow.com/q/70738819/3673430

Comment: Yes it should be possible. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328034/dynamic-jobs-based-on-the-number-of-directories)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables should be stored in a separate template file.  This file ideally would be in a separate repo where other repos can refer to this.

[Here is another answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904150/azure-devops-multi-stage-pipeline-environment-name-not-set-properly/61905038#61905038)